# Getting element from dynamic two dimensional array

Tags: c

Currently, I'm studying c programming language and on the test was a task - Write a function that has two strings as a parameter and need to find and print all unique characters that are present in both strings:

the 'main' function for the test is (and I suspect that all tests are generated using similar function):

```
    int    main(void)
    {
      char *str0 = {"example string", "excelent string"};
      solution(2, str0);
      return (0);
    }
```

Function should be declared as follow `void solution(int size, char **strs);`

I don't see any problem to write algorithm. The question is - **how to get a second string from `**strs`?**

I tried different approaches just to print second element:

```
printf("%s", strs[1]);

*strs++;
printf("%s", *strs);
```

But nothing works.
I guess, that mistake in `main` function:
Should be something like this: `char *str0[] = {"example string", "excelent string"};`

Could somebody help - is this mistake in the test and with a provided function to solve this task is impossible or is exist any way to get second string from array?

Comment: If you know the maximum string length (let's assume it's 15) then you can write `char *str0[15] = {"example string", "excelent string"};`  in `main` function, and in `solution` function just change the first print be exactly like the second print.

Comment: You are assigning an array of pointer to const char to a pointer to char in `str0`. Your compiler should warn you. (Yes, you should be doing the alternative.)

Comment: You can programmatically say `sizeof str0 / sizeof *str0` so you won't have to change the magic number 2 in `size`.

Comment: The initializer `{"example string", "excelent string"}` is the initializer for an **array**. An array of what? (answer: an array of pointers to *string-literals*). How do you declare it? `char *strings[] = {"example string", "excelent string"};` How many elements? `size_t nelem = sizeof strings / sizeof *strings;` (e.g. `2`). How do you iterate over the string? `for (size_t i = 0; i < nelem; i++) puts (strings[i]);` So you have an array of pointers to string literals. You can pass the array of pointers as `char **` because the first level of indirection decays to a pointer.

Comment: To solve your actual problem, in `O(n)`, you'll need some pre-calculation for each string.

Answer (score 0):

`char *str0 = {"example string", "excelent string"};` is incorrect: it declares a character array, but attempts to define it using array of size 2 containing elements of the type 'character array'. It should be declared as an array of arrays, for example using a fixed size of 2. This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void solution(int size, char **strs)
{
  printf("%s\n", strs[0]);
  printf("%s\n", strs[1]);
}

int main(void)
{
  char *str0[2] = {"example string", "excelent string"};
  solution(2, str0);

  return 0;
}
```

I do not consider it a good practice to mix the `*` and `[]` pointer notations, but this follows the specifications of the task best, given the definition of the string literal array of size 2.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comment, your brace-initializer `{"example string", "excelent string"}` is the initializer for an array. (in this case) Specifically in your case, it is the initializer for an *array of pointers* to *String-Literals*.

You declare your array and determine the number of elements by:

```
    char *strings[] = { "one", "two" };
    size_t nelem = sizeof strings / sizeof *strings;
```

Once you have your array of pointers, you can pass the array as type `char **` because the first level of indirection is converted to a pointer on access. See [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Your function declaration can then be:

```
void solution (size_t size, char **strs);
```

and you would invoke your function like:

```
    solution (nelem, strings);
```

A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void solution (size_t size, char **strs)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        puts (strs[i]);
}

int main (void) {
    
    char *strings[] = { "one", "two" };
    size_t nelem = sizeof strings / sizeof *strings;
    
    solution (nelem, strings);
    
    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** while `nelem` and `size` can be type `int`, it is more properly `size_t` -- though the compiler will allow the result of the division to be assigned to `int` without warning)

**Example Use/Output**

Which will iterate over the strings outputting each from the function:

```
$ ./bin/array_ptrs_init
one
two
```

**Determining Unique Characters**

Now for the rest of your task outputting unique characters from both strings, you can include `string.h` and iterate over the characters in one string calling `strchr()` to determine if the character is present in the second string. If it is, `continue;` and get the next char to check, or it it is unique (e.g. `strchr()` returns `NULL`), output the character as unique. (this part I leave to you)

Answer (score 0):

`char*` is the array of chars, that is, char * is string.
And equally, for some type of T, T* is considered as the array of T.
So, you assume that char * is a new type such as

```
typedef char * STRING;
```

Then you can understand easily.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef const char * STRING;

void solution(int size, STRING * strings)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    STRING strings[2] = { "example string", "excelent string" };

    solution(2, strings);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct, but see [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). In 30 lines of code, it's clear what `STRING` is, however in 30,000 lines of code spread over 15 source files -- it becomes a nightmare.

Comment: I agree with your thoughts. I just did that to help understand.